# DateObject from AbsoluteTime broken

Tags: date-and-time

In the middle of a session (10.0.2 / Win64 / 2.7Gb working set - peak was over 7Gb) the form/definition for DateObject from an integer has disappeared.

`DateObject[1]` just returns `DateObject[1]`.

If I run another session `DateObject[1]` gives me a `DateObject`.

`DateObject` is still `Protected`, I didn't `Unprotect` it.

Probably totally un-reproducible, just recording it here in-case it happens again (to someone else).

Comment: I have run into similar problems on OS X, with the new date functions evaporating. Restarting the kernel fixes all.

Comment: Only happened to me once and yes restarting restored them.  Most peculiar though.

Comment: And again, can I legitimately call this a bug?